# Is there an example of AngularJS app generated by Yeoman with e2e tests and $httpBackend?

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, angularjs-e2e, yeoman-generator, httpbackend

Is there somewhere an example of AngularJS app generated by yo angular generator that has e2e tests with `$httpBackend` from `ngMockE2E` module? Preferably with single and continuous versions for CI and development.

It looks like using $httpBackend requires one to create a new app that depends on the original app module and `ngMockE2E` module and requires new index.html file that loads this new app.

If tests use a different app, does it mean that I should modify configuration to store files generated for tests somewhere else than files generated by `grunt server` command (`.tmp`), or will these files be exactly the same? I'd like to be able to have grunt server running for development while running e2e tests in the background with PhantomJS.

Has anyone created a task that automatically generates modified index-e2e.html file based on index.html? This way it would be always up to date and it could also be used with watch to automatically regenerate it whenever original index.html file changes.

Answer (score 0):

You should notice that angular is depreacting e2e in favor of the protractor framework.. Also notice that e2e (and protractor also) is quite slow. so running continuously in the background like we do with unittesting isn't recommended.  That said, for your question - No you don't need a different app, index file etc. (unless you need coverage data from e2e, in that case you'll need to instrument the js files, and that would require a different index.html, that can be created in grunt task with `sed`). what you do need is a different karma.conf.js file, a different grunt karma task ro reference it, including ng-scenario in the `files` section of the karma.conf. and running some kind of `grunt testServer` task that would run a test server, which isn't the same as the dev grunt server. You can run both with foreman or something similiar (as explained in this SO [question]. ([How can I automate both E2E and unit tests with Yeoman & AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737518/how-can-i-automate-both-e2e-and-unit-tests-with-yeoman-angularjs)) and answer). If this is what you are looking for - you can find a karma.conf.js example for both e2e an unit in [this PR](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/pull/94/files). and again, don't invest heavily into the current e2e framework. better working the the new and shiny protractor

Comment: Thanks. [Angular docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E.$httpBackend) state that _"To setup the application to run with this http backend, you have to create a module that depends on the ngMockE2E and your application modules and defines the fake backend."_ So do I need to have a separate index.html file with this new app/module to use fake backend?